# How to make Android app start on pressing on switch

Tags: android

I want to have a situation where an android phone is actually running, so that it might be able receive calls and pressing the on switch, which activates the screen to use apps, actually starts an app running with no further user intervention.

I have seen a similar question which was answered starting with the following advice.
Use BroadcastReceiver that receives Intent of action BOOT_COMPLETED.

However, this appears to be detecting the BOOTING of the phone. In my case a phone is booted and running. I want the app to run because the on switch activates it without any further input. I don't want it to be the  on switch and then activating the app from the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a custom lock screen, which simply starts your app when it launches (which normally happens when the screen turns ON)